# How to avoid In DTE, when setting ProjectItem.Name Visual Studio asks confirmation

Tags: envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I have some  code that sets the "Name" property to change the extension to some file

```
ProjectItem pi = //...
/* snip */
pi.Name = "file.with_new_extension";
```

As soon as the assignation happens, the code pauses, because in the UI Visual Studio is asking confirmation:

"If you change a file name extension, the file may become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?."

Is there any way to stop this confirmation to happen?

Comment: @binaya please review [why your edit was incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4697168), mkay?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was rather simple, using this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.suppressui.aspx
like

```
DTE.SupressUI = true;
```

Before setting ProjectItem.Name, silenced Visual Studio UI.